# Font style isn't applied on PDF (entity print)

Tags: webforms, importing-exporting

I'm using **Entity print** with my **webforms**. I've followed those steps https://www.drupal.org/node/2706755 to add the css into my PDF.

My classes are applied (color, padding...), but for some reason, the **fonts** are never applied on the generated PDF, but is applied on the debug : *https://.../print/pdf/webform_submission/10/debug*

Font are not applied with CDN `@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/aphont');`

or with local font files

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "APHont";
  font-style: Italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  //URLs are OK
  src: url("./font/aphont-bold-italic.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./font/aphont-bold-italic.woff") format("woff"); 
}

body {
  font-family: 'APHont', 'Arial', serif; //even Arial is not applied
}
```

I'm using drupal 9.5.1, entity print 9.11 and DomPDF (i've been digging into others issues on entity print, but could'nt find any matching solution)

Comment: Pretty sure asset includes have to be full URLs / paths on the server and not relative.

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1401#issuecomment-589543115

Comment: It helps. Works with relative, see my answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works by doing this (thanks to this https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1566#issuecomment-591955876) :

1. Using ttf
2. not apply font-family to the body
3. add `font-weight` to each tag you want to apply the font (h1, p...)

The result in css :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "APhont";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url("./font/aphont-bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}

h1 {
  font-family: APhont, serif;
  font-weight: bold; //very important
}
```